# DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter repeatedly called in iOS 14.0 Beta

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This below code for the delay is working well in below iOS 14.0, but in iOS 14.0 simulator, it's repeatedly calling for every 2 seconds. Is there anything I missed it?

```
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { // Change `2.0` to the desired number of seconds.
      // Code you want to be delayed
   }
```

Here I have added the full code :

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("New View"), isActive: $show, label: {
                    Image("main_logo").renderingMode(.original).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                })
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                        self.show.toggle()
                        }
                }
            }  .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
            
            
            
        }.preferredColorScheme(.dark) // white tint on status bar
        
    }
}
```

I am calling New view from here after two seconds, new view dismissed after two seconds and came back to the above view it repeats.

This is what I get in console output

```
[UIContextMenuInteraction] Attempting -[UIContextMenuInteraction dismissMenu], when not in an active state. This is a client error most often caused by calling dismiss more than once during a given lifecycle. (<_UIVariableGestureContextMenuInteraction: 0x60000121a920>)
```

**I am using**
Mac OS -  Big Sur Beta and Xcode 12 Beta

Comment: Works fine here, Xcode 12 / iOS14. Would you elaborate more for demo? I assume it depends on code where you use it.

Comment: Sure, I will update the question

Comment: You’re likely doing something inside the closure that causes the SwiftUI view to be re-rendered (or something along those lines). I’d suggest creating the simplest possible example that manifests the behavior in question (a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @Rob Yeah Ok, Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    self.show.toggle()    // << this !!
    }
}
```

.. `self.show.toggle()` makes `body` rebuild and `NavigationLink` recreated (as it depends on `show`, and thus `.onAppear` called again (as it is new link), and you see - go by cycle.

So nothing wrong with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`.

Probably you meant to attach that .onAppear modifier to root view, ie. probably `NavigationView`.

**Update:** below tested as worked on Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("New View"), isActive: $show, label: {
                    Image("main_logo").renderingMode(.original).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                })
            }  .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
        }.preferredColorScheme(.dark) // white tint on status bar
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                self.show.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, I will try this. But the above code works well in below 14.  I'm little bit of confusion why that's not working in 14.

Comment: @MathankumarK, that is a question to Apple. Btw, I tested .onAppear at root view, see updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62816501/3615605 Can I get any suggestion from you fo this question